# update_by_query for multi field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have added a new `multi field` (`raw`) of an existing field (`response`) in the index. And since the new multi field `raw` will have no data. I tried to add data from source as below.

```
POST /y_metrics/response/_update_by_query
{
  "script":{
    "inline":  "ctx._source.response['raw'] = ctx._source.response;"
  },
  "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

**fails :**

```
 "type": "missing_property_exception",
 "reason": "No such property: raw for class: java.lang.String"
```

**2nd try :**

```
POST /y_metrics/response/_update_by_query
{
  "script":{
    "inline":  "ctx._source['response.raw'] = ctx._source.response;"
  },
  "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

**fails:**

```
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Field name [response.raw] cannot contain '.'"
```

Apparently, the problem seems to be because of ".". But how else one would access `multi field` in this case ? I read about `de_dot` filter does it help in my case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add a field to an existing field (thus a multi field), there is no need to use a script, just reindex and Elasticsearch will handle the rest. You can just drop the `script` part of your update by query call.

Comment: Thanks. If I `reindex` does it not create new index ? because I want to keep the index name as it is. So I can just the run the query without `script` and is equivalent to `reindex` ?

Comment: the only difference between reindex update_by_query is the fact, that reindex allows you to index into another index and update by query does not.

Comment: thanks that seems to work. I can see more results after running `update_by_query` without any `script`.